# How can I ensure that I bind() to and listen() on a "private", rather than "public" network?

Tags: c, winsock2, windows-firewall

In my C program `foo.exe`, I create a TCP socket using winsock2, `bind()` it to a specific port and `listen()` for incoming connections.  Windows 10 throws up its firewall dialog and asks me if I want to allow `foo.exe` to receive connections (a) over private networks, and (b) over public networks.   The "network" in question is a peer-to-peer link-local ethernet connection to a device, so I would certainly think of it as private rather than public. However, the data only gets through if I tell the firewall to allow "public".  I would like to get it to work with just the "private" level of unblocking.

What is the programmer's interface (if any) to determining whether a socket is on a "private" or "public" network in the Windows-Firewall sense?  I expected perhaps to see a way of querying this in the [IP_ADAPTER_UNICAST_ADDRESS_LH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iptypes/ns-iptypes-ip_adapter_unicast_address_lh) specification, but I don't find anything.

I understand that public/private is a property of the network rather than the socket (and even found a way of changing that via PowerShell [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/answers/answers/74554/view.html)), but I guess I need to consider this to be outside the control of my program. I would settle for my program being able to determine, for each adapter returned by `GetAdaptersAddresses()`, whether the network is public or private.

Comment: Private vs public is a property of the Windows network connection and not the program's sockets (not directly at least - of course binding to a specific network will determine the public/private property). Open up Windows "Network and Internet sections", select the network of interest and you will see its public/private setting. You can also change it at that point.

Comment: @kaylum  I see, thank you.  In fact Windows says its Status is "Unidentified network" and lists its Network Category is "Public". Having poked around a bit in its Properties and Properties->Configure->Advanced I don't see an obvious way to change it, but I guess the answer is that it's beyond my program's control anyway.

Comment: @jez You say you are `bind()`'ing your socket to a specific port, but are you `bind()`'ing it to a specific adapter IP as well, or just to `INADDR_ANY`/`in6addr_any`? I'm guessing the latter, which could explain why Windows is prompting you for both public and private networks, since you would be binding to both. If you only want private traffic, then `bind()` to the IP of a private network adapter.

Comment: To determine whether a given network adapter is connected to a public or private network, have a look at the [Network List Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/_nla/), and in particular [`INetwork::GetCategory()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/netlistmgr/nf-netlistmgr-inetwork-getcategory).

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you. And I have found an example I can understand at https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/574446/Using-Network-List-Manager-Cplusplus  Yes you're right, I've been binding to "any" and am thinking I should instead fill the `sockaddr_in` or `sockaddr_in6` from a network entry I know to be private.  I know how to get the `sockaddr` details by iterating through the `IP_ADAPTER_UNICAST_ADDRESS_LH` entries from `GetAdaptersAddresses()`. What I don't yet see is how to know which `IP_ADAPTER_UNICAST_ADDRESS_LH` entry corresponds to which entry in the Network List Manager output...

Comment: @jez `IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES_LH` has a `NetworkGuid` member on Vista+, check if it corresponds to the guid from `INetwork::GetNetworkId()`